# how to set variable to empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am trying to write a function that removes all the elements from an array called `selectedItems`.

It looks like this:

```
  const selectNone = (e: any) => {

    let selectedItemsCopy = selectedItems;
    selectedItemsCopy = []

    setState(
      {
        ...state,
        areAllSelected: false,
        isChecked: false,
        selectedItems: selectedItemsCopy
      }
    );
  }
```

but in setState, selectedItems does not get updated to the empty copy of the array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you have is, that you are actually mutating state, which is basically prohibited in React. In this case, it's very simple to solve, just put the `[]` inside the `setState` directly, without any variables:

```
  const selectNone = (e: any) => {
    setState(
      {
        ...state,
        areAllSelected: false,
        isChecked: false,
        selectedItems: []
      }
    );
  }
```

The method you are using to make a copy of the array, doesn't actually copy the array and instead just creates a reference to the original (that's how JS works). In order to make a proper copy (for example to be able to make modifications, not just clear the array), you should use `Array.from()`.

Here's an example

```
  const selectNone = (e: any) => {

    let selectedItemsCopy = Array.from(selectedItems);
    selectedItemsCopy[x] = changedValue;

    setState(
      {
        ...state,
        areAllSelected: false,
        isChecked: false,
        selectedItems: selectedItemsCopy
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: the `[]` is what I had initially, which also didn't work!

Comment: @helloWorld There must be a mistake somewhere else in your component then, could you provide more of the component?